# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str; error while iterating list

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
list1 = ['Ganga', 'Narmada', 'Kaveri', 'Tapi', 'Yamuna']
sum1 = 0
for i in list1:
  for j in list1[i]:
    sum1 += ord(int(j))
    list1.replace(i, sum1)
print(list1)
```

I want to replace every string of list1 with addition of ascii value of every character of that particular string. for ex. in place of 'Ganga', i want to print (ASCII value of ('G') + ASCII value of ('a') + ASCII value of ('n') + ASCII value of ('g') + ASCII value of ('a') and thus for every string.

I tried as above, but i am getting an error in line

for j in list1[i] as "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

I know, why error has occurred but don't know how to resolve it.
Can anyone please help me in resolving this error.

Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate over the characters of every string in your `list1`, you have to do it like so

```python
for string in list1:
    for char in string:
        ...
```

In your code, the `i` variable will take the values `'Ganga'`, `'Narmada'`, etc. And these are indeed *not* indices, you cannot do `list1['Ganda']`. Hence your `TypeError`.

Because writing `for x in xs` will not give you indices but the items of `xs`, *e.g.*

```python
for x in ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'):
    print(x)
```

will print

```
foo
bar
baz
```